# Hough Lines in video

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, hough-transform

I am trying to make `HoughLines` in my live video stream. I want to detect all edges only around 45 degrees, but the output video has very small lines that look like they are moving. They are not fixed, and are not covering all the relevant edges.

Please see the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while (True):

    s, img = cam.read()

    winName = "Movement Indicator"
    cv2.namedWindow(winName, cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

    edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 4, 2, None, 10, 1)

    if lines is not None:
        for line in lines[0]:
            pt1 = (line[0], line[1])
            pt2 = (line[2], line[3])

            cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
    cv2.imshow('original', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff == ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It would be a good idea if you could post a link to one of your original frames and the corresponding image with edges detected. Then someone can add the images to your question. But if you're looking for 45-degree angles, have you tried Sobel and looking for where the gradient in the x- and y-direction is equal?

Comment: Also, post the results from Canny operation. Majority of data is removed in that stage. And, you're not doing anything in your code for the "45 degree" part.

Comment: a-jays the resolution of angle as given as np.pi/4 is 45 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You use only one array of coordinats:

```
for line in lines[0]:
```

Use this:

```
    if lines is not None:
        for l in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in l:
                cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 255, 255), 20, 5)
```